# Bluetooth headphones unable to hear audio from both Discord and a game

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

My headphones, the Skullcandy Crusher Wirelesses, aren't playing audio from both my Discord call and the game I'm playing. This is pretty annoying since I want to be in a call with some people, but the game itself relies on sound. I got these headphones to avoid all the cables - I don't have a sound-card in my PC.
Help is appreciated. I couldn't find many posts regarding this topic.

Comment: Please edit your question: Sorry to hear about this issue, but without any specifics as to what system you are on — OS and hardware — as well as the exact model number of the Skullcandy Bluetooth headphones, nobody can really help you.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers

(Select Device) Properties\Services\ Disable Handsfree Telephony

or

Settings\Bluetooth & Devices\ Devices\ More devices and printer settings

(Select Device) Properties\Services\ Disable Handsfree Telephony

Please vote up if this helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me!

EDIT: Unfortunately this disabled the mic... It's a win-lose situation! You can hear both discord and game audio but can't talk to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

So the only thing you have to do is to turn on "mono audio" on one of your settings so the talking would be available to your wireless headphones.